# is it possible my threads are not being killed when the server is killed

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

A quartz scheduler is being used in an Application I am working on.  A process that runs using the quartz scheduler spawns new threads.  I was wondering if it is possible for these threads to continue living after the server is killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on whether the threads were [told](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/configuration/ConfigMain.html) to be [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29) threads or not (Quartz defaults to *not*). The JVM will only shutdown when all the remaining active threads are daemon threads.